# I want to generate a single simulated data

Tags: r

I have question on the simulated data in R.

I want to generate a single simulated data. And when I use the following code the code works:

```
set.seed(123465456)

u1<- rep(0, 500); 

for(i in 1:500) {
   u1[i]=rnorm(1);  #Error for first regression
}
```

But I don't want random normal variable. I want to change its mean and variance, then I use the following code, but it does not work. Why?

```
set.seed(123465456)

Q<- rep(0, 500);      

for(i in 1:500) {
   Q[i] = rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=0.2)
}
```

Comment: You are generating 100 values and trying to save it to 1 `Q` value. Just use `x <- rnorm(500, mean=0, sd=0.2)` - and check - `mean(x); sd(x)`

Comment: Using a loop like that is somewhat pointless in R. The base random number generators are designed to return vectors of random numbers. You are just wasting CPU cycles if you insist on assembling those vectors one number at a time.

Comment: Well, it is enough to generate a single simulared random data without using loop? @JohnColeman

Comment: Well, it is enough to generate a single simulared random data without using loop? @thelatemail my assignment question says that “Create a single simulated data series”. For this, is it enough to use only rnorm without loop?

Comment: In fact I try to generate 100 values but 500 simulations @thelatemail

Comment: `rnorm(500)` generates 500 iid (pseudo-)random numbers. If you put those 500 numbers into e.g. 5 sets, you end up with 5 *independent* sets of 100 *independent (and identically distributed)* random numbers.

Comment: If you want 500 simulations of 100 numbers you can do something like `Q <- matrix(rnorm(50000,0,0.2),nrow = 500)` to get a 500x100 matrix of random numbers, where each row can be thought of as a simulation. It takes less than a second to do so.